# Rename Column when reading record using Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

- I am trying use existing google sample code `(PubSubToBigQuery.java)` to parse `StackDriver` log messages and push them into `BigQuery`.
- The problem is one of the SD log field's name is `"@type"` that is not acceptable by BigQuery. So I created that table in `BigQuery` with different field name (mytest).
- Now when I run `PubSubToBigQuery.java` obviously I get the error message that

  > "@type" field not found.
- How can I rename the column name from `"@type"` to `"mytype"` inside my Beam code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to put Stackdriver logs unchanged into BigQuery you can use the built in export feature of Stackdriver and create a sink to BigQuery: https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/

If somehow the export is not feasible for you, you can modify the the transformation logic in Beam.

In this case [PubSubToBigQuery.java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubSubToBigQuery.java) the BigQueryIO uses a TableRow PCollection as input to write the messages into BigQuery. The PubsubMessageToTableRow PTransform does the transformation from PubsubMessage into TableRow with some error handling. 
You can add a ParDo with a custom DoFn which changes the column name in the created TableRow. The process element method could look something like this:

```
 @ProcessElement
 public void processElement(@Element TableRow row, OutputReceiver<TableRow> outputReceiver) {

    TableRow clone = row.clone();
    Object value = clone.get("@type");
    clone.remove("@type");
    clone.set("mytype", value);
    outputReceiver.output(clone);
}
```

If you use the unchanged PubSubToBigQuery.java I linked you can apply this ParDo on the `jsonToTableRowOut.get(TRANSFORM_OUT)` PCollection somewhere around line 323 in the code.

Comment: Like this?: 
.and(TRANSFORM_OUT, jsonToTableRowOut.get(TRANSFORM_OUT).apply("RenameCol", ParDo.of(new RenameColumnFn())))

    static class RenameColumnFn
            extends DoFn<PubsubMessage, FailsafeElement<PubsubMessage, String>> {
        @ProcessElement
        public void processElement(@Element TableRow row, OutputReceiver<TableRow> outputReceiver) {

            TableRow clone = row.clone();
            Object value = clone.get("@type");
            clone.remove("@type");
            clone.set("mytype", value);
            outputReceiver.output(clone);
        }
    }

Comment: Yeah, something like that, only the supertype of RenameColumnFn should be `DoFn<TableRow, TableRow>` like this `static class RenameColumnFn extends DoFn<TableRow, TableRow> {`

Comment: I guess I am missing something. I am still getting:   
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Insert failed: [{"errors":[{"debugInfo":"","location":"protopayload.@type","message":"no such field.","reason":"invalid"}],"index":0}]
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.flushRows(StreamingWriteFn.java:142)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.StreamingWriteFn.finishBundle(StreamingWriteFn.java:103)

Comment: Because it is other column, not the "@type" but the "protopayload.@type" column. You need to reset the name for that column in the created TableRow also.
There can be other columns like that, so your pipeline can became hacky.  Are you sure you cannot use the built in export function of Stackdriver to do this instead of writing a custom Beam pipeline?

Comment: Thanks.    @type is the only mismatch. I changed it to this and still giving the same error: 
      TableRow clone = row.clone();
      Object value = clone.get("protopayload.@type");
      clone.remove("protopayload.@type");
      clone.set("protopayload.@mytype", value);
      outputReceiver.output(clone);
      value = clone.get("@type");
      clone.remove("@type");
      clone.set("@mytype", value);
      outputReceiver.output(clone);

Comment: sorry. my bad. I should have had "mytest" instead of "@mytest". now it's working. thanks